# Get public photos from Instagram using Facebook extended page token

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, facebook-access-token

Is there a way to do hashtag search on Instagram public photos using an extended page token already obtained on Facebook ?

Any examples with actual APIs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hashtag search and public content is not supported in Instagram Graph API, you can only get the authenticated Instagram Business Account's posts and stories

And as of Oct 1 2017, `public_content` is no longer approved in the original Instagram APIs, which would have let you do hashtag search and get public posts.

Comment: Can public photos be searched on Facebook using Graph API and an extended page token already obtained ?

Comment: No, graph API is like basic, u can only get your photos and insights if your account is business acoount